# full width/stretch a website background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I get a website background image to be full width/stretch with no space at the side and top. I do not know whether it is html, css or javascript I have to use to do this.

[click here for an example of what i would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2e0s.png)

Here is my CSS code:

```css
section{
    
    max-width:100%;
 height:700px;
 background-size:cover;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

Comment: Howdy, welcome to SO. For starters, take it out of that section you have a fixed height on, and max-width 100% doesn't make much sense either. Instead just do something like `body {background: #fff url(blah/img/path.png) no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;}` and you're done, if I'm understanding your question correctly anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of different way to do this, actually it's all depends upon developer.

this code might help you.

```css
section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0,
  left:0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: #0e0e0e;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<section><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2e0s.png" /></section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML, CSS, or Javascript depending on your needs. Each programming language offers its own advantages and disadvantages:

#### HTML

**Pros:** The pure HTML way is the simplest, most straight forward way to insert an image. The HTML way is also the fastest and most beneficial to the page load speed because, since you are telling the browser the dimensions of the image in advance, the browser is able to present the page to the user sooner than when it gets done loading the image.

**Cons:** The pure HTML way is the least responsive, the least customizable, and the least extensible. You have to individually micromanage each and every image.

**How:** Follow the below steps.

1. Create an image tag.
2. (Optionally) set this image tag's `decoding` attribute to `async` to prevent the loading of the image from blocking the page load speed.
3. Set the `width` attribute to either a number of pixels or a percentage of the initial-containing surrounding box (a super advanced concept, please do not worry about it!).
4. Set the `height` attribute to either a number of pixels or a percentage of the initial-containing surrounding box (a super advanced concept, please do not worry about it!).
5. Set the `alt` and `src` attribute.

Working example:

```html
48% X 48%:<br />
<img width="48%" height="48%" src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_129e9184-f7fd-4a07-b455-a49df70c7c99?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg" alt="Big brand &quot;California&quot; rasins" decoding="async" />
<br />488px X 488px (original size, reccomended):<br />
<img width="488" height="488" src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_129e9184-f7fd-4a07-b455-a49df70c7c99?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg" alt="Big brand &quot;California&quot; rasins" decoding="async" />
<br />48px X 48px:<br />
<img width="48" height="48" src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_129e9184-f7fd-4a07-b455-a49df70c7c99?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg" alt="Big brand &quot;California&quot; rasins" decoding="async" />
```

#### CSS

**Pro:** Much more freedom and expressibility than the HTML way. With CSS, you can set constraints on the minimum and maximum size in addition to setting the prefered way. You can also scale your image based on font size so it looks good on all devices and scale it to the size of the screen and use `calc` to create complex calculations

**Con:** Suffers from the same lack of extensibility as HTML.

**How:**

```css
html, body, #bloat {
  width: calc(22vh + 22vw + 1em + 8px);
  height: calc(48vh + 48vw - 2em - 1px);
  margin-left: 1em;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(-9deg) rotateZ(-2deg);
  perspective: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d8/ba/c5/d8bac51eebcaea95eb6eeee1d6f01885.jpg" id="bloat" alt="What?"/>
```

#### Javascript

**Pro:** You can use the original size of the image in your calculations. This is a major plus because it allows for highly scalable web designs to be created.

**Con:** It is way way slower and page-blocking than HTML or CSS. This is especially true for people who do not know how to code Javascript, and are instead just copying snippets of javascript to paste all over their website because Javascript is unprecedentedly easy to misuse. However, do not be discouraged too much: in the right hands with the right usage, javascript can be incredibly powerful.

**How:** I am assuming that, because of the nature of the question you are asking, that you do not know javascript. Alright, I can work with that. The template HTML code is given below. The below code should be IE6+ compatible. However, it is quite likely that the rest of your page is not IE6-compatible.

The guide below assumes little/no knowledge of Javascript. You must follow the instructions to the point in the code below.

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    var images = document.images || document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var ddEle = document.documentElement;
    /*****************************/
    /** [Place Piece-1 Extensions Here] **/
    /*****************************/
    function whenResize(){
        /*****************************/
        /** [Place Piece-2 Extensions Here] **/
        /*****************************/
        for (var i=0,Len=images.length; i < Len; ++i) {
            var theImage = images[i];
            /*****************************/
            /** [Place Piece-3 Extensions Here] **/
            /*****************************/

            theImage.width = /*Insert equation:*/ 1 + 1;
            theImage.height = /*Insert equation:*/ 1 * 1;
        }
    }
    if (document.readyState !== "interactive") {
        whenResize();
    } else if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", whenResize, {once: 1});
    } else {
        document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function onReady(){
            document.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", onReady);
            whenResize();
        }); // old IE
    }
    if (typeof addEventListener === "function")
        addEventListener("resize", whenResize, {passive: 1});
    else
        attachEvent("onresize", whenResize); // old IE
})();
```

In Javascript, whitespace only matters inside of numbers and variable names. For example, <strike>`102 e -10`</strike>, <strike>`1. 02`</strike>, <strike>`108 273 651.905`</strike>, or <strike>`108,273,651.905`</strike> are invalid numbers. `device Font Size`  is an invalid variable name. But, `102e-10`, `1.02`, and `108273651.905` are all valid. `deviceFontSize` is a valid variable name solong as you set up the plugin correcytly  Below is a list of Javascript operators that you can use in the equations.

- Addition: `a + b`

```js
console.log(3 + 4);
console.log(3+4);
```

- Subtraction: `a - b`

```js
console.log(3 - 4);
console.log(3 - 4);
```

- Multiplication: `a + b`

```js
console.log(3 * 4);
console.log(3*4);
```

- Division: `a + b`

```js
console.log(3 / 4);
console.log(3/4);
```

- Modulus: `a % b`

  - Gives the remainder of the division of `a / b`

```js
console.log(3 % 4);
console.log(3%4);
```

- Greater Than Ternary: `a > b ? c : d`

  - Gives `c` if `a > b`
  - Otherwise, gives `d`

```js
console.log(3 > 4 ? 9 : -90);
console.log((3 > 4 ? 55 : 9) % (12 - (1 > 1 ? 9 : 8)));
```

- Greater Than Or Equal To Ternary: `a >= b ? c : d`

  - Gives `c` if `a >= b`
  - Otherwise, gives `d`

```js
console.log(3 >= 4 ? 9 : -90);
console.log((3 >= 4 ? 55 : 9) % (12 - (1 >= 1 ? 9 : 8)));
```

- Less Than Ternary: `a < b ? c : d`

  - Gives `c` if `a < b`
  - Otherwise, gives `d`

```js
console.log(3 < 4 ? 9 : -90);
console.log((3 < 4 ? 55 : 9) % (12 - (1 < 1 ? 9 : 8)));
```

- Less Than Or Equal To Ternary: `a <= b ? c : d`

  - Gives `c` if `a <= b`
  - Otherwise, gives `d`

```js
console.log(3 <= 4 ? 9 : -90);
console.log((3 <= 4 ? 55 : 9) % (12 - (1 <= 1 ? 9 : 8)));
```

<sub>(Note that for the purpose of simplicity, I only gave examples of `>`/`<`/`>=`/`<=` in ternary expressions even though neither do ternary expression require these operators nor are these operators only usable in ternary expressions)</sub>

The extensions are listed below. Please only use these extensions "as-needed" to ensure maximum performance. The setup code for each extension should only be inserted once at each place. Do not insert the setup code multiple times.

- Font size extension

  - Gives you the user's font size as the variable `deviceFontSize`. Be aware that on some devices, the font size can change over the course of the user's visit to the page. But, unfortunately, there is no good solution that exists to deal with these devices. The easiest way to deal with this these devices (if you absolutely have to) is to swap the places of the following "Piece-2" code with "Piece-1" code.
  - Piece-1 code: `var gCompStyle=window.getComputedStyle;`
  - Piece-2 code: `var deviceFontSize = parseFloat((gCompStyle ? gCompStyle(ddEle,null) : ddEle.currentStyle||{}).fontSize)||16;`
  - Piece-3 code: [none]
- Screen size extension

  - Gives you the size of the user's screen as the variables `deviceWidth` and `deviceFontSize`
  - Piece-1 code: [none]
  - Piece-2 code: `var deviceWidth=window.innerWidth, deviceHeight=window.innerHeight; if (deviceWidth === undefined) deviceWidth = ddEle.offsetWidth, deviceHeight = ddEle.offsetHeight;`
  - Piece-3 code: [none]
- Natural image size extension

  - Every image file gets saved as being X pixels by Y pixels. This extension gets the dimensions of the original image file as variables `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`. It defaults to 0 if it could not get these values.
  - Piece-2 code: [none]
  - Piece-2 code: [none]
  - Piece-3 code: `var naturalWidth = theImage.naturalWidth | 0, naturalHeight = theImage.naturalHeight | 0;`
- Natural image size extension

  - Every image file gets saved as being X pixels by Y pixels. This extension gets the dimensions of the original image file as variables `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`. It defaults to 0 if it could not get these values.
  - Piece-2 code: [none]
  - Piece-2 code: [none]
  - Piece-3 code: `var naturalWidth = theImage.naturalWidth | 0, naturalHeight = theImage.naturalHeight | 0;`
- Math extension

  - See [this MDN set of pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) for a list of all mathematical functions. If there is a "Polyfill" section on the page for the math function that you want, then copy and past that poyfill code into the "Piece-1 code" section.
  - Now, to ensure speed, drop off the `Math.` from the math methods and insert the following code only once per each method used (not once per each usage of the method). For example, if you used *Math.abs* three times, then the piece-1 code would be `var abs=Math.abs;`. If you used *Math.pow* once and *Math.log* 4 times, then your piece-1 code would be `var pow=Math.pow;var log=Math.log;`. After you insert these extensions, you would use the math function normally without the `Math.`. For example, you might use `Math.max` along with the *Window Size extension* and set the width of the image to `max(deviceWidth, deviceHeight)` to get the maximum of the width and the height of the screen.
  - Piece-1 code: `var` (put the name of the math function here. E.x. put `cos` if you want *Math.cos*) `= Math.` (also put the name of math function here. E.x. put `cos` if you want *Math.cos*) `;`
  - Piece-2 code: [none]
  - Piece-3 code: [none]

#### Full Example:

```js
delete eval; delete Proxy; // exorcise JS evil and redeem performance's soul!
(function(){
    "use strict";
    var images = document.images || document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var ddEle = document.documentElement;
    /*****************************/
    /** [Place Piece-1 Extensions Here] **/
    // The Font Size extension
    var deviceFontSize = parseFloat((ddEle.currentStyle || getComputedStyle(ddEle, null)).fontSize);
    // Math functions:
    var max = Math.max;var min = Math.min;
    /*****************************/
    function whenResize(){
        /*****************************/
        /** [Place Piece-2 Extensions Here] **/
        // the device width extension:
        var deviceWidth=window.innerWidth, deviceHeight=window.innerHeight; if (deviceWidth === undefined) deviceWidth = ddEle.offsetWidth, deviceHeight = ddEle.offsetHeight;
        /*****************************/
        for (var i=0,Len=images.length; i < Len; ++i) {
            var theImage = images[i];
            /*****************************/
            /** [Place Piece-3 Extensions Here] **/
            // The natural size extension:
            var naturalWidth = theImage.naturalWidth | 0, naturalHeight = theImage.naturalHeight | 0;
            /*****************************/
            theImage.width = (deviceWidth * 30/100 + 15*deviceFontSize + naturalWidth * 2) / min(max(naturalWidth, 1), 3);
            theImage.height = (deviceHeight * 210/100 - 3*deviceFontSize + naturalHeight * 2) / min(max(naturalHeight, 1), 3);
        }
    }
    if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
        whenResize();
    } else if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", whenResize, {once: 1});
    } else {
        document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function onReady(){
            document.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", onReady);
            whenResize();
        });
    }
    if (typeof addEventListener !== "undefined")
        addEventListener("resize", whenResize, {passive: 1});
    else
        attachEvent("onresize", whenResize); // old IE
})();
```

```html
<img src="https://s1.nyt.com/timesmachine/pages/1/1993/10/20/766893_360W.png" alt="Medical Article In Foreign Language" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

body { 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-image: url(your-img-url);
}
```

This is it

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
body {
    background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000);
    background-size: cover;
  }
```